# animate a Rectangle moving smoothly android view

Tags: android, drawing, android-animation

I have multiple rectangles in the middle of the view (canvas). I want to move them all to the edges of the screen smoothly simultaneously.  This is not a jump, i need to see the between positions from start to end so it appear as a smooth transition.

Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: BouncingBalls.java sdk samples folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public class animatedView extends View {
    Bitmap i;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;

    public animatedView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        i = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Rect bk = new Rect();
        bk.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        Paint pBk = new Paint();
        pBk.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        pBk.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(bk, pBk);
        canvas.drawBitmap(i, x, y, pBk);
        x+=10;
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I didnt try it, but shouldn't this loop forever. I dont think the rectangles would stop at the edges.
My objective is to on a button click move the rectangles to the edges withing the bounds of the canvas drawing area and stop the animation.

Also, is there a way to stop touch events been executed during the animation.

Comment: But you can make it as you want  you  have  the code  and  you can  add simple statments to attend your objective just a little bit of thinking , in this case you can make a test on the coordinate x if it attends the edge it will stop incrementing

Comment: yes you can  stop the touch event of a button like this : btn.setEnabled(false); 
and with  some  test statments you have to create it by yourself you can stop it only during the annimation , it's so easy

Comment: I meant the touch event on the canvas. Becoz user can drag the rectangles. This has to be stopped when the animation is going on.

Comment: I don't know how you have implemeted the touch event on the canvas , so can you post your code , I'll try to help you

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. Is there a way to stop the app to listen to user touch events when the animation is going on. Otherwise it could be messy, if the user tries to drag the rectangle while it is being animated pragmatically. Only way I can think of is, when the button is pressed by the user set a boolean say (isAnimating) and then in 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) { if (isAnimating) return;..}. Is there a better way?

Comment: you can make view.setEnabled(!isAnimating);